# Android target gets changed after doing cordova platform update

Tags: java, android, node.js, cordova, build

I am trying to update my existing cordova project from android 3.6.4 to 3.7.2 ...
The target specified in the project.properties is set to 'android-19' before the update. 
But when I do the update it is changed to 'android-21'.

> mac$ cordova -v
>
> > 4.3.0
>
> mac$ cordova platforms ls
>
> > Installed platforms: android 3.6.4, browser 3.5.2, ios 3.7.0
> >     Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, firefoxos

This is the command i use to update the cordova android

> mac$ cordova platforms update android@3.7.2
>
> > Updating android project...
> >     Android project is now at version 3.7.2
> >     If you updated from a pre-3.2.0 version and use an IDE, we now require that you import the "CordovaLib" library project.
>
> mac$ cordova platforms ls
>
> > Installed platforms: android 3.7.2, browser 3.5.2, ios 3.7.0
> >     Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, firefoxos

At this point the android/build.properties have target=android-21.

On my local machine I have android SDKs upto 22 , so it works fine locally. But on deployment box 19  is the limit. So no chance of updating the SDK version over there.

Here is what happens if I manually change target in build.properties to android-19

> -compile:
>       [javac] Compiling 98 source files to /build/path/a/long/one/platforms/android/CordovaLib/ant-build/classes
>
> ```
> [javac] //build/path/a/long/one/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:35:
> ```
>
> error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac] import android.webkit.ClientCertRequest;
>       [javac]                      ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
>       [javac]   location: package android.webkit
>       [javac] //build/path/a/long/one/platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient.java:145:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>       [javac]     public void onReceivedClientCertRequest (WebView view, ClientCertRequest request)
>       [javac]                                                            ^
>       [javac]   symbol:   class ClientCertRequest
>       [javac]   location: class CordovaWebViewClient

**and so on.....**

I have tried many things to change the target but nothing good happened so far. 
My config.xml has the min and target sdk settings in it.

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>  
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
```

And above lines do result in updating the AndroidManifest.xml file , but thats about it. no effect whites ever on project.properties files.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't  know if this is going to help anyone or not but this is my 2 cents on this issue:

There is no way of downgrading the target level in android/build.properties file. So keep it to 21 or 22 . The reason being: cordova library uses Android API 21 + libraries ... so it is going to complain if you try to downgrade it.

You can manage the target SDK settings in config.xml and it will take care of genrating the AndroidManifest.xml file accoordingly. So in short if the  target set in build.properties is 21 even then you can run the app on android devices running lower versions.

Hopefully this helps.